# web service deployment error - tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat

When I try to deploy my web application I get the following error message. Tomcat version 7.0.40. When I remove endpoint code and web service code I can deploy my application. I read that this method ()V  error occured when there is no constructor for somebody else but his application was not a web service application. Where should i put default constructor ????

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodE
rror: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not
found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController
: method <init>()V not found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAs
sembler.<init>(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.doCreate(Tubeli
neAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TubelineAssemblerFactory.create(TubelineAssem
blerFactory.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:170)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:306
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:301
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.
java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:574)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:557)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapter
s(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:260)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(Deploy
mentDescriptorParser.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseA
daptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.o
nStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5370)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1654)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Haz 03, 2013 1:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletE
xception: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMetho
dError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V no
t found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.o
nStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5370)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1654)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11
: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.w
s.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController: method <init>()V not found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseA
daptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:141)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.o
nStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssembl
yController: method <init>()V not found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAs
sembler.<init>(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.doCreate(Tubeli
neAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TubelineAssemblerFactory.create(TubelineAssem
blerFactory.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:170)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:306
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:301
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.
java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:574)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:557)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapter
s(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:260)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(Deploy
mentDescriptorParser.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseA
daptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
        ... 14 more

Haz 03, 2013 1:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Haz 03, 2013 1:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Haz 03, 2013 1:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Haz 03, 2013 1:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14455 ms
```

Comment: My endpoint publisher only has a main method. I can run it from netbeans ide and after that I can reach web service from browser or client but I can not deploy endpoint and webservice code as a part of my web application.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? Because I am having the same problem..

Comment: I entered this question a while ago. We used it as I mentioned in the question :( We couldn't find a way to deploy with the endpoint